# SQLite multiple queries one UITableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, uitableview

So right now I have populated my `UITableview` with data from an `SQLite` database, how I do it is by populating a `NSMutableArray` which then populates my `UITableview`. Right now my I am only using one Query to get the data from the database but I want to be able to change that query dependant on what cell the user presses on. Here is what the array looks like:

```
-(NSMutableArray *) authorList{
     _theauthors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
    @try {
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"StayhealthyExercises.sqlite"];
    BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
    if(!success)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", dbPath);
    }
    if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
    {
        NSLog(@"An error has occured: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));

    }

    const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM strengthexercises WHERE primarymuscle LIKE '%abdominal%'";

    sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }else{

        while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
            sqlColumns * author = [[sqlColumns alloc] init];
            author.Name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,1)];
            author.Muscle = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,2)];
            author.Description = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 3)];
            author.File= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 4)];
            author.Sets= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 5)];
            author.Reps= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 6)];
            author.Equipment= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 7)];
            author.PrimaryMuscle= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 8)];
            author.SecondaryMuscle= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 9)];
            author.Difficulty= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)    sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 10)];

            [_theauthors addObject:author];
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
@finally {
    sqlite3_close(db);

    return _theauthors;
}
}
```

As you can see this is my query:

```
const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM strengthexercises WHERE primarymuscle LIKE '%abdominal%'";
```

I want this to change dependant on what cell the user presses on?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1.save query type when user press cell. 2.change your query condition by the query type you saved.

Comment: Well its good way to learn but in production you can not run code like this, I think you should use a better way to handling the database, if you are going to use SQLite as database then here is the superb lib which can work for you https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

Comment: @johnMa could you give an example?

Comment: @Retro why is this bad practice?